# Rails 'simple_form' Not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am currently working on a Wiki app using Rails and I have done most of the back end work now I am just styling the app. I having trouble with the simple_form. I have run through all the necessary installations re: the simple_form but still no result. My project is in HAML and I am using Bootstrap. Please find an image relating to the result I am getting in the browser and what the code looks like:

[Browser View](http://tinypic.com/r/2r3gvp2/8)

```
#simple_form_for @article do |f|
#f.input :title
#f.input :content
#f.submit
```

Would appreciate any type input from anyone, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

based on the screenshot, you're printing the code in the html. You need to use the '=' to make haml evaluate the rails code. Something like:

```
= simple_form_for @article do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.submit
```